# Identifying the preferred IPv6 source address for an adapter

Tags: linux, macos, solaris, ipv6

If you have a IPv6 enabled host that has more than one global-scope address, how can you programmatically identify the preferred address for `bind()`?

Example address list:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:5e:bd:6d:da  
          inet addr:10.6.28.31  Bcast:10.6.28.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2002:dce8:d28e:0:214:5eff:febd:6dda/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::214:5eff:febd:6dda/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2002:dce8:d28e::31/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

On Solaris you can indicate a preferred address with an interface flag and it is available programmatically via `SIOCGLIFCONF`:

```
/usr/include/net/if.h:
#define   IFF_PREFERRED   0x0400000000    /* Prefer as source address */
```

As listed in the interface list:

```
eri0: flags=2104841<UP,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DHCP,ROUTER,IPv6> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet6 fe80::203:baff:fe4e:6cc8/10 
eri0:1: flags=402100841<UP,RUNNING,MULTICAST,ROUTER,IPv6,PREFERRED> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet6 2002:dce8:d28e::36/64
```

This is not portable to OSX, Linux, FreeBSD, or Windows though.  Windows is let off easy though as it has completely useless, from an administrators perspective, UUID based adapter names (depending upon the Windows version).

For Linux [this article](http://www.davidc.net/networking/ipv6-source-address-selection-linux) details how the parameter `preferred_lft`, where `lft` is short for "lifetime", can be altered to weight the selection process by the kernel.  This setting doesn't appear conveniently available in the results of `SIOCGIFCONF` or `getifaddrs()` though.

So I want to bind to `eth0`, `eri0`, or whatever available interface name.  The choices are a bit stark:

1. Fail on adapter names resolving to multiple interfaces.  I take this approach for handling multicast transports ([OpenPGM](http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/)) as the protocol MUST have one-only sending address.
2. Bind to everything.  This is a cop out and would be unexpected to users.
3. Bind to the adapter with `SO_BINDTODEVICE`.  This requires `CAP_NET_RAW` system capability on Linux which can be quite a cumbersome overhead for administrators.
4. Bind to the first IPv6 interface on the adapter.  The ordering tends to be completely bogus.
5. Bind to the last interface.  [David Croft](http://www.davidc.net/networking/ipv6-source-address-selection-linux)'s article implies Linux does this, but is also a bit bogus.
6. Enumerate over every interface and create a new socket explicitly for each.

With option #6 I would expect you could usually be smarter and take the approach that if only a link-local scope address is available bind to that, otherwise bind to just the available global-link scope addresses.

When connecting to another host then [RFC 3484](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt) can be used, but as you can see all the choices are dependent upon matching the destination address:

1. Prefer same address. (i.e. destination is local machine)
2. Prefer appropriate scope. (i.e. smallest scope shared with the destination)
3. Avoid deprecated addresses.
4. Prefer home addresses. Prefer outgoing
   interface. (i.e. prefer an address on the interface we're sending
   out of)
5. Prefer matching label.
6. Prefer public addresses.
7. Use longest matching prefix.

In some circumstances we can use #7 here, but in the interface example above both global-scope interfaces have a 64-bit prefix length.

[RFC 3484](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt) has the following pertinent lines:

> The IPv6 addressing architecture [5](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt) allows multiple unicast
> addresses to be assigned to interfaces.  These addresses may have
> different reachability scopes (link-local, site-local, or global).
> These addresses may also be "preferred" or "deprecated" [6](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2462.txt).

The link being to [RFC 2462](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2462.txt), similarly expanded:

> preferred address - an address assigned to an interface whose use
> by
> upper layer protocols is unrestricted. Preferred addresses may
> be used as the source (or destination) address of packets sent
> from (or to) the interface.

But no methods to programmatically acquire this detail.

Props to Win32 API that exposes an ioctl [SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_SORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that allows a developer to use not only RFC 3484 sorting but to take into consideration any system administrator overrides.  Linux has `/etc/gai.conf` as used for RFC 3484 sorting in `getaddrinfo()` but no API for directly accessing the sorting.  Solaris has the `ipaddrsel` command.  OSX is following FreeBSD by adding `ip6addrctl` in 10.7.

**edit:**  Some concerns with RFC 3484 sorting are listed and referred to in this additional IETF draft document:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-axu-addr-sel-01

> Solaris, for example, creates new alias-interfaces for each new
> address assigned to a physical interface.  So if_index could also be
> used to uniquely identify a source address specific routing table on
> that platform.  Other operating systems do not work the same way.

The author likes Solaris's approach of giving each additional IPv6 interface a new alias, so that `eri0` would become the link-local scope address, and `eri0:1` or `eri0:2`, etc, must be specified to use a global-scope address.

Clearly whilst a nice idea one couldn't expect to see other OS change for quite some time.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to bind to a specific address instead of letting the OS choose for you?

Comment: @Sander deployment in multi-NIC environments, for example you might have the Internet, DMZ, intranet, or have networks dedicated to certain traffic flows, such as raw incoming data, processed data, and client traffic.

Comment: I understand. Usually I try to make sure that the default behaviour works, for example by using global addresses for external communication and ULA for the internal NIC so that longest prefix matching works, but that is not always possible. And it doesn't work when sending to a multicast destination because ULA always has a longer match. Specifying the source address to bind to in a config file is an option..

Comment: I understand that it is a bit outdated. But have you found the answer to your question?

Comment: @Sergey not yet, I will regularly review each new platform to see if new options have appeared to implement said functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is in the direction you're seeking, but...

Poking around in the iproute bundle's `ip` code (`ip/ipaddress.c`) under linux shows that the `ip` command digs up interface flags like `primary` and `secondary` from a `struct ifaddrmsg`, member `ifa_flags`.  The `ifaddmsg` seems to be acquired through a `struct nlmsghdr` which is documented in `man 7 netlink`, and used via `sendmsg` and `recvmsg` interaction with the kernel, which overall sounds like a royal pain but it's at least programmatic.  Whether primary and secondary would be enough to be useful is a separate question.

Comment: Eventually down the rabbit hole, a `RTM_GETADDR` request can be sent over netlink to return a list of addresses for IPv6 with an attribute `IFA_CACHEINFO` which includes the parameter `ifa_preferred` which if is zero is not-preferred.